# How can you apply enable_if_t template restriction to entire class with separated implementation code, if possible?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, implementation, enable-if

Note: I prefer to *always* keep my implementations separate from my declarations, even for template code that must still go in the header. So I tend to have a `.h` file for the declarations, and at the bottom of that file include a `.hpp` file for inline and template implementations, then put my non-inline, non-template implementations in `.cpp` files. It may not be possible to follow that preference in this case, or I may be doing something wrong.

I have this initial code, which compiles and runs:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

#define OddSource_Export __attribute((visibility("default")))

class IPAddress {};
class IPv4Address : public IPAddress {
public:
    uint8_t version() const {
        return 4;
    }
};
class IPv6Address : public IPAddress {
public:
    uint8_t version() const {
        return 6;
    }
};

template<class TAddress>
class OddSource_Export InterfaceIPAddress
{
public:
    InterfaceIPAddress(TAddress const &, uint16_t);
    uint8_t version() const;
private:
    ::std::unique_ptr<TAddress> const _address;
    uint16_t const _flags;
};

template<class TAddress>
InterfaceIPAddress<TAddress>::
InterfaceIPAddress(TAddress const &address, uint16_t flags)
    : _address(new TAddress(address)),
      _flags(flags)
{}

template<class TAddress>
uint8_t
InterfaceIPAddress<TAddress>::
version() const
{
    return this->_address->version();
}

int main()
{
    IPv4Address addr4;
    InterfaceIPAddress<IPv4Address> address(addr4, 0);
    std::cout << "Version: " << std::to_string(address.version()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But I want a simple base class restriction. So I started by defining this alias:

```
template<class TAddress>
using Enable_If_IPAddress = ::std::enable_if_t<::std::is_base_of_v<IPAddress, TAddress>>;
```

Changing my class declaration as follows:

```
template<class TAddress, typename = Enable_If_IPAddress<TAddress>>
class OddSource_Export InterfaceIPAddress
```

And changing my construction and method implementation as follows:

```
template<class TAddress, typename>
```

Here's the new version:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

#define OddSource_Export __attribute((visibility("default")))

class IPAddress {};
class IPv4Address : public IPAddress {
public:
    uint8_t version() const {
        return 4;
    }
};
class IPv6Address : public IPAddress {
public:
    uint8_t version() const {
        return 6;
    }
};

template<class TAddress>
using Enable_If_IPAddress = ::std::enable_if_t<::std::is_base_of_v<IPAddress, TAddress>>;

template<class TAddress, typename = Enable_If_IPAddress<TAddress>>
class OddSource_Export InterfaceIPAddress
{
public:
    InterfaceIPAddress(TAddress const &, uint16_t);
    uint8_t version() const;
private:
    ::std::unique_ptr<TAddress> const _address;
    uint16_t const _flags;
};

template<class TAddress, typename>
InterfaceIPAddress<TAddress>::
InterfaceIPAddress(TAddress const &address, uint16_t flags)
    : _address(new TAddress(address)),
      _flags(flags)
{}

template<class TAddress, typename>
uint8_t
InterfaceIPAddress<TAddress>::
version() const
{
    return this->_address->version();
}

int main()
{
    IPv4Address addr4;
    InterfaceIPAddress<IPv4Address> address(addr4, 0);
    std::cout << "Version: " << std::to_string(address.version()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, now my constructor fails to compile:

```
warning: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name InterfaceIPAddress<TAddress>::InterfaceIPAddress; implicit 'typename' is a C++20 extension [-Wc++20-extensions]
    InterfaceIPAddress<TAddress>::
    ^
    typename 
error: expected ')'
    InterfaceIPAddress(TAddress const &address, uint16_t flags)
                                ^
note: to match this '('
    InterfaceIPAddress(TAddress const &address, uint16_t flags)
                      ^
error: expected ';' at end of declaration
        : _address(new TAddress(address)),
        ^
        ;
error: no template named '_address'; did you mean 'TAddress'?
        : _address(new TAddress(address)),
          ^~~~~~~~
          TAddress
```

And the `version()` method fails with similar errors. This is on Clang14. GCC also has various compiler errors, but they are different:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class InterfaceIPAddress’
   38 | InterfaceIPAddress(TAddress const &address, uint16_t flags)
      |                                                           ^
main.cpp:26:24: note: declaration of ‘class InterfaceIPAddress’
   26 | class OddSource_Export InterfaceIPAddress
      |                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I'm pretty sure that I'm defining the `enable_if_t` correctly, because if I move my implementation to be inline with the declaration, it compiles without warning or error. So this works:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

#define OddSource_Export __attribute((visibility("default")))

class IPAddress {};
class IPv4Address : public IPAddress {
public:
    uint8_t version() const {
        return 4;
    }
};
class IPv6Address : public IPAddress {
public:
    uint8_t version() const {
        return 6;
    }
};

template<class TAddress>
using Enable_If_IPAddress = ::std::enable_if_t<::std::is_base_of_v<IPAddress, TAddress>>;

template<class TAddress, typename = Enable_If_IPAddress<TAddress>>
class OddSource_Export InterfaceIPAddress
{
public:
    InterfaceIPAddress(TAddress const & address, uint16_t flags)
        : _address(new TAddress(address)),
          _flags(flags)
    {}
    uint8_t version() const
    {
        return this->_address->version();
    }
private:
    ::std::unique_ptr<TAddress> const _address;
    uint16_t const _flags;
};

int main()
{
    IPv4Address addr4;
    InterfaceIPAddress<IPv4Address> address(addr4, 0);
    std::cout << "Version: " << std::to_string(address.version()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So am I missing some extra step I need to go through for the separated implementation? Or is it not possible to separate this implementation when using `enable_if_t`?

Also, I tried adding a `typename` where the compiler suggested, but all that did was satisfy the warning. No compile errors were solved.

**EDIT: This should be re-opened**

I do not understand why this question was closed. It says, "Edit the question to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem." Those edits were already performed, and the question could not possibly be any clearer than it now is. Plus, it has a complete and accepted answer already. Closing this question is nonsensical and hinders others' ability to find helpful information.

Comment: please show a [mre]. Have you tried adding a `typename` as suggested by the compiler?

Comment: Edited as suggested.

Comment: Still not a [mre], more of an incomplete jigsaw puzzle with bits we need to glue together and other bits missing

Comment: This would be easier to analyze at if you edited your post to include _complete files_ for each translation unit in your MRE. Preferably, each file would begin with a comment giving its name, e.g., `// main.cpp`, `// A.h`, `// A.hpp`, and `// A.cpp`. That way, we could easily try to compile your code ourselves.

Comment: I have rewritten the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you added an extra template parameter for the class, you need to pass it into the implementation declaration, for example

```
template<class TAddress, typename Enable>
InterfaceIPAddress<TAddress, Enable>::
InterfaceIPAddress(TAddress const &address, uint16_t flags)
    : _address(new TAddress(address)),
      _flags(flags)
{
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fbez68TMn) with your reduced example.

However, for your example, simply using `static_assert` is a more appropriate option, which eliminates the extra template and provides better diagnostics:

```
template<class TAddress>
class OddSource_Export InterfaceIPAddress
{
  static_assert(std::is_base_of_v<IPAddress, TAddress>, 
    "the template parameter TAddress must derived from IPAddress");
public:
  // ...
};
```

Comment: I have `, typename>`, which is what I see in documentation and other examples for the use of `enable_if_t`. What is `typename Enable`?

Comment: @NickWilliams `, typename Enable>` is to name the unnamed typename as `Enable` to facilitate passing in `InterfaceIPAddress<TAddress, Enable>::InterfaceIPAddress` to conform to the definition of class, which accepts two template parameters.

Comment: Okay, I changed `, typename>` to `, typename Enable>` and recompiled. The Clang and GCC compiler errors are identical to those shown in the question above.

Comment: Did you also change `InterfaceIPAddress<TAddress>::` to `InterfaceIPAddress<TAddress, Enable>::`?

Comment: Sorry, I had to step away for a couple hours. Indeed, that was the solution. But I'd love to understand this a bit better, if you have a minute to expand on this. In a separate case (see https://godbolt.org/z/Wb6v9qs5e), where I'm templating only a method and not the whole class, just `, typename>` suffices, and I don't have to use `Enable` or similar.

Comment: I think we are seeing the difference between [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) for a function, and [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) for a class, but I could be wrong.

Comment: There's a lot to unpack there, but I get the gist of why they're different. One more question, and at this point I'm just trying to understand this better, even though I think you're probably right and a `static_assert` is better for this ... there's a behavior difference between that function template I linked to and the above class template code when I specify the wrong type. Function: Clang says "requirement 'is_same_v......' was not satisfied," GCC says "template argument deduction/substitution failed" and points to the `is_same_v`. Different but both helpful. However...

Comment: ...for the class template, both Clang and GCC say something entirely unhelpful. "no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::enable_if’ ... using enable_if_t = typename enable_if<_Cond, _Tp>::type;." (But, again, only if I specify the wrong type, so it does, at least, "work.") This seems to suggest I'm doing something wrong in my declarations. Am I?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you're doing. There are several popular ways to use `std::enable_if_t`, including the way you've used it. SFINAE was not originally intended as a meta-programming tool. It is not surprising that the error message it generates are less precise than the ones you can sculpt yourself in a `static assert`. See the [Examples at CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) for a few other `enable_if` idioms...

Comment: Note, however, that many of them are being replaced by the [`requires` clause from C++20](https://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2022/06/20/requires-expressions-and-requires-clauses-in-cpp20/). It is even cleaner than `static_assert`, for example: `template<class TAddress> requires std::is_base_of_v<IPAddress, TAddress> class InterfaceIPAddress { ... }`.

Comment: Yeah, I look forward to being able to use `requires`...